# How to return consistent data types in laravel pagination

Tags: laravel

I have a function that returns staff and there associated attributes as below

```
foreach ($merchant_user_ac->staffs->sortByDesc('id') as $staff) {
  $wage = Staff::find($staff->id)->totalCommissions($start_date, $end_date);

  $payments = StaffPayment::where('merchant_id', AH::cMiD())
    ->where('user_id', $staff->id)
    ->when(!empty($start_date) && !empty($end_date), function ($q) use (
      $start_date,
      $end_date
    ) {
      $q->whereBetween(\DB::raw('date(payment_date)'), [
        $start_date,
        $end_date,
      ]);
    })
    ->sum('amount');

  $balance_owed = $wage - $payments;

  $transactions->add([
    'id' => $staff->id,
    'name' => $staff->name,
    'profilephoto' => $staff->profilephoto,
    'wage' => $wage,
    'payments' => $payments,
    'salary' => $staff->salary,
    'rent' => $staff->rent,
    'balance_owed' => $balance_owed + $staff->salary - $staff->rent,
  ]);
}

$merchant_staffs = collect(json_decode(json_encode($transactions), false));
$merchant_staffs = $merchant_staffs->paginate(10);
return response()->json($merchant_staffs);
```

In the results, the first page is OK but the subsequent pages are having a different data type from the first page and displaying the data becomes an issue.

[image: This is the response for the first page]

[image: This is the response for the second page]

The data key has different data types.
I have tried paginating before the foreach loop but the response did not have the pagination links.
I have tried adding `->toArray()` method when collecting the data but has the same issue of different types.

How can I return the same data in all pagination links?

The data returned is as below

```
{
"current_page": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 532,
        "name": "George2",
        "profilephoto": "photos/GwSIKoIXUk1GdL7boD7Ht9mSp1loxM1nGcZ5l5Gd.jpg",
        "wage": 0,
        "payments": 10000,
        "salary": "90000.00",
        "rent": "1000.00",
        "balance_owed": 79000
    },
    {
        "id": 528,
        "name": "david",
        "profilephoto": null,
        "wage": 100,
        "payments": 0,
        "salary": "67000.00",
        "rent": "67000.00",
        "balance_owed": 100
    },
    {
        "id": 524,
        "name": "Naggie",
        "profilephoto": null,
        "wage": 0,
        "payments": 0,
        "salary": null,
        "rent": null,
        "balance_owed": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 503,
        "name": "Khaki ",
        "profilephoto": null,
        "wage": 0,
        "payments": 0,
        "salary": null,
        "rent": null,
        "balance_owed": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 502,
        "name": "Susan",
        "profilephoto": null,
        "wage": 0,
        "payments": 0,
        "salary": null,
        "rent": null,
        "balance_owed": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 476,
        "name": "Maggie",
        "profilephoto": null,
        "wage": 0,
        "payments": 17000,
        "salary": null,
        "rent": "15000.00",
        "balance_owed": -32000
    },
    {
        "id": 475,
        "name": "Aggy",
        "profilephoto": null,
        "wage": 0,
        "payments": 15000,
        "salary": "15000.00",
        "rent": null,
        "balance_owed": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 465,
        "name": "Rhoda",
        "profilephoto": null,
        "wage": 0,
        "payments": 0,
        "salary": null,
        "rent": null,
        "balance_owed": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 464,
        "name": "Very New Staff",
        "profilephoto": null,
        "wage": 500,
        "payments": 0,
        "salary": "10000.00",
        "rent": null,
        "balance_owed": 10500
    },
    {
        "id": 422,
        "name": "jane",
        "profilephoto": null,
        "wage": 0,
        "payments": 0,
        "salary": "15000.00",
        "rent": null,
        "balance_owed": 15000
    }
],
"first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/staff/list?page=1",
"from": 1,
"last_page": 3,
"last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/staff/list?page=3",
"links": [
    {
        "url": null,
        "label": "&laquo; Previous",
        "active": false
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/staff/list?page=1",
        "label": "1",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/staff/list?page=2",
        "label": "2",
        "active": false
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/staff/list?page=3",
        "label": "3",
        "active": false
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/staff/list?page=2",
        "label": "Next &raquo;",
        "active": false
    }
],
"next_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/staff/list?page=2",
"path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/staff/list",
"per_page": 10,
"prev_page_url": null,
"to": 10,
"total": 25
}
```

[image: Expected data]

Comment: That is really weird.... could you show us at least one entry when `data` is a `json` and when it is an `array`? Also, does this happen when you directly do `return $merchant_staffs->paginate(10);` instead of `response()->json`?

Comment: Both  return `$merchant_staffs->paginate(10);`  and `return response()->json($merchant_staffs);` return the same data as shown in the images.

Comment: Sample data returned?

Comment: @davidkihara I would not do what the answer is saying, just because it works is not always the answer... the code should ALWAYS return an array of jsons, even if you get 1 back... and you still did not share what is being returned when you get a data as json instead of array, but whatever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$pagination = $merchant_user_ac->staffs()->latest()->paginate(10);
$data = $pagination->getCollection()->map(function ($staff) {
    $wage = Staff::find($staff->id)->totalCommissions($start_date, $end_date);

  $payments = StaffPayment::where('merchant_id', AH::cMiD())
    ->where('user_id', $staff->id)
    ->when(!empty($start_date) && !empty($end_date), function ($q) use (
      $start_date,
      $end_date
    ) {
      $q->whereBetween(\DB::raw('date(payment_date)'), [
        $start_date,
        $end_date,
      ]);
    })
    ->sum('amount');

  $balance_owed = $wage - $payments;

  return [
    'id' => $staff->id,
    'name' => $staff->name,
    'profilephoto' => $staff->profilephoto,
    'wage' => $wage,
    'payments' => $payments,
    'salary' => $staff->salary,
    'rent' => $staff->rent,
    'balance_owed' => $balance_owed + $staff->salary - $staff->rent,
  ];
});

return response()->json($pagination->setCollection($data));
}
```

Comment: I would not mark this as a correct answer, you are "reproducing" what `paginate` should do, so there is somethin deeper (wrong) in the code... Defnitely never do this...